# Automatically execute a PHP script

Tags: php

I am currently developing a website. Users can post ads which are added in a database.
I would like to delete these ads when they are more than 60 days old.
To do so, I will write a PHP script which will find such ads and delete them from the database.

Right, it's easy. But how do I execute this script without loading a page every day in my browser ? How do I ask to my server to execute it automatically regularly ?

Thanks !

PS : I am on a shared server, not a dedicated one. Does it make cron use not possible ?

Comment: With cron jobs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: There are 3rd-party sites that can visit your site regularly. I use cron-job.org personally, although. it's in german.

Comment: Here is a guide for cron jobs on shared hosting servers: http://drupal.org/node/117351. FYI I use dreamhost, and they offer cron  job support, so you should be all ok.

Comment: Seems to be an interesting solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following:

- Use `cron` to automate the task ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron))
- If you wish to have the page as a web page you'll want to use `wget` to load the web page ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget))
- Alternatively, use PHP from the command line by doing something like `/path/to/php /path/to/script.php` - you need to make sure you give this file (script.php) executable permissions. ([more info](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php))

**Edit**: You can use cronjobs on a shared server, what control panel is available to you? (cPanel, Plesk, etc.)

Comment: I am on a shared server, not a dedicated one. Can I use cron anyway ?

Comment: It's a specific interface (of a french host provider). I will check if it's proposed in my interface.

Comment: It should be, almost all hosts provide cronjobs.

Comment: Right, there is this feature. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 5):

Is it Unix/BSD/Linux hosting? Then you are after [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: I am on a shared server, not a dedicated one. Can I use cron anyway ?

Comment: Well, ask your hosting provider. There's a big chance that you have cron jobs on you account.

Comment: Prisoner answered first ;) +1 anyway.